# Shortcut key to expand the selected collapsed block/region in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

It is very frustrating to hold mouse just when my cursor is on the correct location but I can't expand the block.

I use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
, 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
 to collapse to definition. But not able to expand one of the block after that. I have to hold the mouse and click on the plus sign.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> toggles expansion.

Comment: Why not Ctrl + M only, just saying

Comment: @Code: For me, this didn't work back then. (I haven't been working with VS for years now.)

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me when i tried like this - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> ,<kbd>M</kbd> ; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> ;